# Show that a finite dimensional algebra D with identity over a skewfield F is a semifield if and only if it has no zero divisors.

Tags: abstract-algebra, division-algebras

I'm struggling with a proof of the next lemma.

Show that a finite dimensional algebra $D$ with identity over a skewfield $F$ is a semifield if and only if it has no zero divisors.

EDIT:

Actualy I have skewfield $F$ with centre $Z$ and $\theta$ which is anti-automorphism of $F$ of finite order $m$ and $a, b$ elements of $F$, all such that:
$F$ has finite dimension over $Z$ and $x x^{\theta}$ is in $Z$ for all $x$ in $F$a and that $a=x^{\theta +1} + xb$ has no solution for $x$ in $F$.

Now I have two-dimensional vector space $D$ over $F$ with basis elements 1 and $\lambda$, where we use multiplication $(x + \lambda y)(z + \lambda t)=(xz + aty^{\theta}) + \lambda (zy + x^{\theta} t + y^{\theta}bt)$ so that $D$ becomes semifield.  So for semifield I would have to check that for or every $x + \lambda y$ and every nonzero $p + \lambda q$ in $D$, there exist unique $z + \lambda t$ and $u + \lambda v$ in $D$ for which $(x + \lambda y)(z + \lambda t) = p + \lambda q$ and $(u + \lambda v)(x + \lambda y) = p + \lambda q$.

But in my book they say that because of the lemma above we only have to show that the only solutions for $(x + \lambda y)(z + \lambda t) = 0$ are $(x + \lambda y) = 0$ or $(z + \lambda t) = 0$.

Comment: If $D$ is a finite dimensional algebra over a field $F$, then this is a standard exercise: For $a \in D$ consider the linear endomorphism of $D$ given by $x \mapsto ax$ and use the fact that endomorphisms of a finite dimensional vector space are injective if and only if they are surjective. However, can you clarify what you mean by (i) an algebra over a skewfield (ii) a semifield?

Comment: Semifield: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_ring

Comment: I must say I've never heard this terminology used for a skew field. Is some book using this? Then, What is a skewfield for you? For me: Skewfield=division ring=nonzero ring in which every element is invertible. Also, you still have not explained what an algebra over a skewfield should be.

Comment: Yes, skewfield means the same for me. I've expanded my question, is it now more clear?

Comment: Ok, now it's clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your expanded description $D$ is a finite-dimensional algebra over a (commutative) field $Z$.

> I claim that for $a \in D$ the following two statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. $a$ is not a  left zero-divisor (i.e. there exists no $b \in D \setminus  \{0\}$ with $ab=0$).
> 2. $a$ is left invertible (i.e., there exists $c \in D$ with $ca=1$; or equivalently, for all $y \in D$, there exist $x \in D$ such that $xa=y$).

**Proof:** Consider the map $\mu_a\colon D \to D$, $x \mapsto ax$. This is a $Z$-linear endomorphism of $D$. Since $D$ is a finite-dimensional $Z$-vector space, $\mu_a$ is injective if and only if it is surjective. Now note that $\mu_a$ is injective if and only if statement 1 holds. Similarly, $\mu_a$ is surjective if and only if statement 2 holds.

Now your lemma follows easily by what I just proved and the symmetric statement where 'left' is replaced by 'right'.

**Remark.** The fact that every non zero-divisor is a unit holds in more general settings. For instance, it is true for Artinian rings. This includes as a special case finite-dimensional algebras over a field, but also finite rings. It is also true for von Neumann regular rings.

Comment: Thank you very much, it took me some time but I think I understand what you mean - we take $D$ over $Z$, because we need commutativity in proof of linear endomorphism. The only thing I don’t understand is if we have equivalence between the two statements for $D$ over $Z$ how can we just assume that it is the same for $D$ over $F$ (because to me it feels like you don’t get the all the elements in $D$ if you take $D$ over $Z$ instead of $F$)?

Comment: Actually, if you are familiar with (right) vector spaces over division rings, you could also do it over $F$. Then $\mu_a$ will be a right $F$-linear endomorphism and the same argument applies. The two statements don't mention $Z$ at all. It is only assumed in the proof of their equivalence that $D$ is a finite-dimensional $Z$-algebra, which it is, since $\dim_Z D = \dim_Z F \cdot \dim_F D$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience! :D

Comment: You're welcome!